# mail command sends empty body if file attached

Tags: ubuntu, mail-command

Whenever I attach a file to mail like:

```
$ mail -A attachment.pdf -s"Subject" id@domain.com
Cc:
This body never gets sent.
```

And hit `Ctrl+d` to send the mail. The attachment and the subject get sent, but the **body remains blank**.

Everything works fine when I send an email without an attachment. I don't understand where I am going wrong. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @K7AAY is this a ubuntu specific problem? I don't know..

Comment: Sure doesn't happen with my Debian

Comment: Same here on Debian 10